# Sqlalchemy ProgrammingError exception: Unknown column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

here are the files which contain my code:

this is models.py file

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import func

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')

class Note(db.Model):
    time = func.now()
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=time)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

and this is views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from .models import Note
from . import db

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/notes', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def notes():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = request.form.get('note')
        new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
        db.session.add(new_note)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('notes.html', user=current_user)
```

I got the error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
> (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1054 (42S22): Unknown column
> 'user_id' in 'field list' [SQL: INSERT INTO note (id, data, date,
> user_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(data)s, now(), %(user_id)s)] [parameters:
> {'id': 1, 'data': 'get a ', 'user_id': None}]

Any idea on where I messed

up and how to fix it ?

Comment: Error is saying that there is no column `user_id` in the actual `note` table. Can you please check the table in your SQL database. If possible please share the screenshot of the table.

Comment: yes, I checked in the database and you were right the column was not made, not really sure how that happened. But now I'm facing another problem, when I pass current_user.id to user_id when making a Note instance i'm getting this error: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'localproxy' cannot be converted to a MySQL type.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I think `current_user.id` is not giving you actual id that you want. You need to check first by debugging the code. First print the value of `current_user.id` and it's type then you will get the better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed a problem similar to this. My code was trying to insert one of the Column values into one of the Column names. Like the others have suggested, examine your code within the database. Here are some examples of my code before and after:

### incorrect variable: self.all_output_data

```
self.user_tables = f"""
    INSERT INTO voicechannel_{self.my_name_and_id}
    (my_input,  msg_from_input, self.all_output_data, my_output) 
                         VALUES
    ('{self.my_input_widget}','{self.all_input_data[0]}',
     '{self.all_output_data}','{self.output_to_other_nodes[0]}')
"""
```

### correct variable: msg_to_output

```
self.user_tables = f"""
    INSERT INTO voicechannel_{self.my_name_and_id}
    (my_input,  msg_from_input, msg_to_output, my_output) 
                         VALUES
    ('{self.my_input_widget}','{self.all_input_data[0]}',
     '{self.all_output_data}','{self.output_to_other_nodes[0]}')
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code from

```
new_note = Note(data=note, id=current_user.id) 

to 

new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
```